# Making a carousel in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

Currently having an issue with JSON in AngularJS, where I select the 'img' object, it console logs, but doesn't apply to the scope. Can anyone shed any light?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('AppliedSiteApp').controller('CarouselCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // CAROUSEL IMAGES
    var carouselImages = [
        {
            "img": "background-image: url('images/carousel/carousel1.jpg')"
        },
        {
            "img": "'background-image': 'url(images/carousel/carousel2.jpg)'"
        },
        {
            "img": "'background-image': 'url(images/carousel/carousel3.jpg)'"
        },
        {
            "img": "'background-image': 'url(images/carousel/carousel4.jpg)'"
        },
        {
            "img": "'background-image': 'url(images/carousel/carousel5.jpg)'"
        },
        {
            "img": "'background-image': 'url(images/carousel/carousel6.jpg)'"
        },
        {
            "img": "'background-image': 'url(images/carousel/carousel7.jpg)'"
        },
        {
            "img": "'background-image': 'url(images/carousel/carousel8.jpg)'"
        }
    ];

    // SET INITIAL CAROUSEL IMAGE
    $scope.carouselImage = carouselImages[0].img;

    console.log('image', $scope.carouselImage);

});
```

I am trying to apply this to the scope with:

```
<div class="carousel" ng-style="carouselImage"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use angular-carousel . See this

[angular-carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel)